# Keeping customer secrets safe from sysadmins and devs in Kubernetes

Tags: secrets-management, kubernetes, multi-tenancy, zero-trust

I've spent a few weeks on GCP and GKE (Kubernetes) trying to figure out how to store customer secrets. The secrets are used by some application even when the user is not logged on so I want to ensure no human can reach to them.

A lot of places including Google Cloud's documentation mention Envelope Encryption and that's fine. But it seems that no matter what the approach I've tried to dig into, as the owner of the project I seem to always be able to somehow get access to the secrets. E.g. in Kubernetes you can always do `kubectl get secret` or run `kubectl exec` on the machine and these permissions seem impossible to remove for the "superadmin".

So how do companies actually manage this so that secrets are not visible by any human?

Comment: What do you mean by customer secrets? Do you need to encrypt the data of each user so that only this user can decrypt them?

Comment: @mentallurg no, in my case I want a program to read them on file (or similar), but disallow any human being reaching that file. So on restarts, the program can continue acting on user's behalf but no devops or admins can read the secrets.

Comment: If only particular user should be able to decrypt some data, then ask user for a password for these data. If the application needs to decrypt the data independent on particular user, then somebody should provide password/secret to the application, and such person is called administrator. So what is the problem?

Comment: @mentallurg the problem is that in Kubernetes any admin can get inside the container and peek around. So they will see the secret. Or if it is encrypted, they will hold the key to decrypt it

Comment: @JohanHanssenSeferidis: *"in Kubernetes any admin can get inside the container and peek around."* - so you basically ask for a setup where you can protect your data from the admins of the container platform and/or cloud environment you are using. I think this currently kind of impossible, i.e. you need to trust the administrators of your chosen environment the same as you need to trust the developers of the environment for not introducing backdoors. In the future confidential computing might give you some more assurance.

Comment: @JohanHanssenSeferidis: 1) Admins are not random persons. Admins are trusted persons. If you don't trust admins, you should not deploy anything in such environment. 2) If some organization gives admin roles to not trusted persons, it is organizational question, not a security question, and that's why it is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes, a [cluster administrator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/) is a role that requires [elevated privileges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/), which [are not constrained by access rights](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/rbac-good-practices/#least-privilege). As such, a cluster administrator can read/modify any object (including secrets) in kubernetes. That's by design.

But even if you could restrict their access to a secrets file, they could easily circumvent the access restriction, due to the fact that they can modify the said cluster at will; so they could sniff, alter, impersonate or do whatever else they wanted in order to access the secrets.

And that's without taking into account the node-level access to your cluster; a system administrator of the node(s) that host(s) the control plane of your cluster is much more difficult to restict<sup>[a]</sup>.

> So how do companies actually manage this so that secrets are not visible by any human?

If by *any human* you refer to the kubernetes admins, then the answer is that they choose trustworthy people to manage the kubernetes clusters, who will not abuse their privileges (and have signed the respective legal documents that go with their positions). For anyone else, the companies just place access controls that restict the access to the said secrets.

---

<sup>[a]</sup> Nodes are typically linux boxes, which require system administrators for maintenance

Comment: Trust but verify: you choose people you trust for administrators, but still ensure there's an impossible (for them) to remove audit trail of such actions.

Comment: And if you want to do that you set the log to be immediately written out to WORM media, and/or a system under control of different admins.